# how to use camera ontology in ROWLEX

Tags: camera, ontology, rowlex

I'm mot sure if I'm doing this wrong or not
I don't know if I am supposed to add other ontologies

If not, what can I do to get a camera ontology working please?

http://protege.cim3.net/file/pub/ontologies/camera/camera.owl

Thanks

Comment: yep ok, but what do you want to do ?

Comment: its not working in ROWLEX. in the OWLGrinder. I dont know what I am doing wrong

Comment: I edited my response. Please, see that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried you ontology with the OwlGrinder, and I indeed got an error message. (Next time please, report that). 
Normally these messages report if your ontology is not valid. In your case, your ontology is OK, ROWLEX assumed that maxCardinality is always greater than zero, but according to the [OWL spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl-ref/#maxCardinality-def), zero is a perfectly valid value. Therefore, this is a bug in ROWLEX, I recorded it, it will be fixed in the next version.

As a temporary solution, you need to change the ontology if you want to use ROWLEX. You can get rid of the restriction of #shutter-speed, or you may change the restriction like this:

```
<owl:maxCardinality>1</owl:maxCardinality>
```

instead of

```
 <owl:cardinality>0</owl:cardinality>
```

Important! The proposed change alter the meaning of your classes significantly, but it shuts OwlGrinder up.

Comment: sorry i forgot to add the link http://protege.cim3.net/file/pub/ontologies/camera/camera.owl

Comment: any idea when the next release will happen?!